# WCF RESTful service initialization

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, rest

I'm getting a bit confused because I'm retrieving information which I can't relate to my situation.

Briefly, I have created a new WCF service application in my VS2008 (.NET 3.5sp1). In the project I have the Service.svc file (plus service.svc.cs), the IService.cs and finally the web.config file.
I've written my methods and I've modified the web.config file as needed to obtain a REST service, and all is working. But now I need to setup the logger object (specifically, the log4net object), and I started wondering about the right place to do the initialization.

Here come the things I do not understand. Searching the internet for information, I found many articles talking of application file (as the global.asax), or doing initialization where the ServiceHost object is created, in a Main method.

I do not have such files in my solution, hence my confusion arises. Have I created the wrong type of project? Or is it just sufficient to add a global.asax file? And what is the right place to do such operations (initializations...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the global.ascx / global.ascx.cs files into a WCF project by right clicking the project, selecting add file then select "Global Application Class".

The 'right place' for the initialisation depends on how and what kind of logging you want to do. If you only have one logger and aren't logging based on endpoint, etc, then there is no harm in initialising it statically somewhere within your application (i.e. a static constructor). And then using this logger from everywhere within the application (just don't expose the set method).